# Does a vhost specific .conf settings over-ride the ssl.conf settings?

Tags: https, apache2, configuration

In my mods-available/ssl.conf

( It is also symlinked in mods-enabled )

I have these lines:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
```

For my vhost I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@good-health.ml
    ServerName good-health.ml
    ServerAlias www.good-health.ml
    DocumentRoot /var/www/good-health.ml

    <Directory /var/www/good-health.ml>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/good-health/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/good-health/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!DH:!EXPORT:!RC4:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!LOW:!aNULL:!eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/mycerts/good-health.ml/cf_origin_cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/mycerts/good-health.ml/cf_private_key.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Does the virtual host specific config over-ride the ssl.conf ?

Perhaps I should delete those lines in ssl.conf and just have them in
the vhost. Your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the virtual host specific config over-ride the ssl.conf ?

Yes.
The question is not where the directives are nor in what order, the question is where each directive sits in which section.

From https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html:

> The configuration sections are applied in a very particular order.
> Since this can have important effects on how configuration directives
> are interpreted, it is important to understand how this works.
>
> The order of merging is:
>
> ```
> <Directory> (except regular expressions) and .htaccess done simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed, overriding <Directory>)
> <DirectoryMatch> (and <Directory "~">)
> <Files> and <FilesMatch> done simultaneously
> <Location> and <LocationMatch> done simultaneously
> <If>
> ```
>
> Some important remarks: [..]
>
> Sections inside <VirtualHost> sections are applied after the
> corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This
> allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.

FWIW, unrelated to your question directly but related to settings "SSL" in Apache, the following can be helpful: https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/

Among other things it does the right thing of `SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1` (SSLv2 should be long gone in your library stack anyway but you are not specifying versions of what you are using)

Comment: Thanks, I have commented out the lines in ssl.conf and just have them in the vhost